# Teechart :How to move a visible series mark by code?

Tags: delphi, teechart, delphi-xe4

In a `TLineSeries` called `serie1` with parent chart `cht1`, where I have visible marks, I'm trying to move one mark by code. My problem is that when I try to set mark position's Custom property to true, I get an "access violation" exception. But, if I drag the mark (with a TDragMarksTool attached to the chart and active) it moves. After that, "custom" position is true and I can move the mark by code.

This in one button's click event.

```
serie1.Marks[10].Visible:=True;
serie1.Marks.Positions.Position[10].Custom:=true; <<< Exception here.
```

I'm using Delphi XE4 and Teechart 2014, don't have my laptop here to see the exact version numbers.

Comment: Call `Invalidate` rather than `Draw` to force a repaint. As for your exception, how can we comment? What is the exception? Be precise. Don't make us guess. I'd guess that `serie1.Marks.Positions.Position[10]` was out of bounds, but why do we need to guess.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, David. But it doesn't resolves the main problem; I get the exceptions before the Draw call.

Comment: What would really help would be if you could produce a better question with a complete reproduction of the issue. As I said above, it's tough when we have to guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some properties aren't initialized until the chart has been entirely drawn.
Try forcing a chart repaint calling `cht1.Draw;` before accessing `serie1.Marks.Positions.Position` array.